# how to disable aToolTip function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I'm using [aToolTip](http://ara-abcarians.com/jquery/atooltip/) library form my tool tips, but I cant find in its documentation how to disable it. I' using different text on image click by click count. `0 = '1st text', 1 = '2nd text', 2 = 'disabled'`

```
        $("#toolt").aToolTip({   
            tipContent: 'Pažymėkite kairę akį'  
        }); 
        $(".bg_image").click(function(e) {
            nrOfClicks++;
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
            var relativeY = (e.pageY - offset.top);    

            if (nrOfClicks == 1){
                $("#toolt").aToolTip({   
                    tipContent: 'Pažymėkite dešinę akį'  
                }); 
            }   
            if (nrOfClicks == 2){
                $('.bg').remove();
                $("#toolt").unbind('mouseover');
                $(".bg_image").css('cursor', 'default');
            } 
            if (nrOfClicks <= 2){   
                $(this).each(function() {
                    x_coords[nrOfClicks] = relativeX;
                    y_coords[nrOfClicks] = relativeY;
                });

                $('<div>', {
                    'class':'point',
                    'css': {
                        'position': 'absolute',
                        'left':     relativeX +'px',
                        'top':      relativeY +'px',
                        'width':    '3px',
                        'height':   '3px',
                        'background-color': '#fff'
                    }
                })
                .appendTo('#output');
            } 
        });
```

Tried on 2nd click to remove id `#toolt` but tooltip still working. Any advices?

Comment: Your probably making this more difficult than it needs to be. You should basically have the tooltip selector on anything you want to be a tooltip. If you dont want it to be a tooltip, dont have the id/class on it.

Comment: It's a little unclear - are you trying to change the content based on the number of clicks?

Comment: @Jay Blanchard yes, if image is clicked 2 times I need to disable tooltip.

Comment: Disabling the tooltip is different than changing the content of the tootip. Which do you want to do?

Comment: @Alex Tooltip is activated when user uploads a photo, aTooltip is needet to show what user have to selecet in the photo (left and right eyes) 0 click = left eye tooltip, 1st click = right eye tooltip, 2nd click disable tooltip.

Comment: @JayBlanchard disable the tooltip

Comment: Try $('#toolt').unbind('aToolTip');

Comment: @JayBlanchard That didint worked. Cant imagine what else coud work on that :/

Comment: `$(".bg_image").unbind();
                $('#aToolTip').hide();` that worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I found a hacky way how to disable aToolTip event.

```
            $(".bg_image").unbind();
            $('#aToolTip').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to unbind the mouseover event:

```
$("#toolt").unbind('mouseover')
```